# Realm BadVersionException

Tags: android, realm

I have started getting the below error, seemingly at random. I am grabbing a Realm Object and using it to render the screen, I am also (potentially) updating said RealmObject in a background (networking) thread.

I am using Realm Java 2.3.0.

Any hints as to how I could investigate this further would be great!

Gav

```
java.lang.Error: io.realm.internal.async.BadVersionException: std::exception in /home/cc/repo/realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_TableQuery.cpp line 1143
    at io.realm.AndroidNotifier.throwBackgroundException(AndroidNotifier.java:138)
    at io.realm.RealmQuery.closeSharedRealmAndSendEventToNotifier(RealmQuery.java:2239)
    at io.realm.RealmQuery.access$000(RealmQuery.java:62)
    at io.realm.RealmQuery$5.call(RealmQuery.java:2179)
    at io.realm.RealmQuery$5.call(RealmQuery.java:2153)
    at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityCallable.call(BgPriorityCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: io.realm.internal.async.BadVersionException: std::exception in /home/cc/repo/realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_TableQuery.cpp line 1143
    at io.realm.internal.TableQuery.nativeFindWithHandover(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.TableQuery.findWithHandover(TableQuery.java:448)
    at io.realm.RealmQuery$5.call(RealmQuery.java:2162)
    at io.realm.RealmQuery$5.call(RealmQuery.java:2153) 
    at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityCallable.call(BgPriorityCallable.java:36) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: The honest answer is that the object store notification system shouldn't be used together with direct core async queries, but it is and therefore async queries are a bit unstable until 2.4.0 is done. It's sad because 1.2.0 did not have this problem.

Comment: Cheers EpicPandaForce. I haven't had an issue since 2.3.1 but that could be coincidence. I will keep my eye out for 2.4.0 and see what happens then.

Comment: Hey Epic, would you mind elaborating a little on "object store notification system shouldn't be used together with direct core async queries"? I am wondering if I have structured things incorrectly or if this is something internal to Realm?

Comment: Totally internal to Realm. Version 2.x just wasn't ready at time of release, and still isn't. This is just what I think, though. Once [3834 is merged](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3834), it'll be a bit better though.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Add the following class path dependency to the project level build.gradle file.

`buildscript {

```
repositories {

    jcenter()

}

dependencies {

    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"

}
```

}`

Step 2: Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of application level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I have realm up and running (it is a great DB!). I just have this frustrating issue every now and again (currently Testing 2.3.1 to see if that helps me out).